# Can we draw illustration of animal footprints, human skull ,beard and moustache?

Tags: drawing, art

I'm learning illustration and I'm very much concerned about what are the things that are permissible in art in Islam.

**I know that any illustration/drawing of a living creature is prohibited**

My main concern is can I draw illustration of animal footprints, human skull, beard and moustache.
Please help me and Thank you!

Comment: If the second picture is of a woman then please remove it for the sake of Allah. The first picture is also not appropriate as it says merry christmas, which some may even consider shirk to say.

Comment: The prohibition is on what might be recognized as a full "description" of a such a being. And Allah knows best.